# How to use PostgreSQL on AWS - Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: sql, amazon-ec2, ubuntu

I'm extremely new to cloud-computing, Linux, and PostgreSQL, so if this is a stupid question, I apologize.

I've managed to create an m1.large instance running Ubuntu 11.10, connect via Putty SSH, and install PostgreSQL (`sudo apt-get install postgresql`), but that is as far as I've gotten.

My goal is to run several python web-scraping scripts that I've written on this instance (so as not to eat up all of our bandwidth (smaller company at the moment)) and insert the scraped data into a PostgreSQL table on the instance and later retrieve that data to store on our local server (as I've heard AWS EBS is unreliable and I don't want to take chances).

How can I configure PostgreSQL on my AWS instance? How can I access the data from my machine? I currently use PgAdmin3 to manage PosgreSQL on our local server. Can I use this same interface to manage PostgreSQL on my AWS instance?

Any suggestions, solutions, links, etc is greatly appreciated. And again, if this is a dumb question, I apologize.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to open an inbound port([mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9209370/722658)) for postgresql on your EC2 instance. I am not an expert of postgresql but it should be 5432 if you are using defaults.

You may follow [help.ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL)'s documentation to configure postgre, especially you need to make postgre listen to network in order to accept connections from internet via changing the related line in postgresql.conf to: listen_addresses = '*'. This [entry](http://deadprogrammersociety.blogspot.com/2009/08/postgresql-on-ubuntu-on-ec2.html) would be useful

After these steps you may connect to your postgre via your usual PgAdmin3 by entering your public DNS address of your EC2 instance(something like "ec2-3-3-25-16.compute-1.amazonaws.com") as host address. Or you may use [Elastic IP](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346) feature of AWS to assign a simpler IP address to your EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks! I've got PostgreSQL properly configured. Its up and running, but when I try to connect with PgAdmin3, I receive an error stating the server doesn't listen.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to uncomment `listen_address` in `postgresql.conf` Got it!